# App is getting crash on accepting incoming video call with PJSIP

Tags: ios, video-streaming, pjsip

App is getting hang after accepting incoming video call with PJSIP.
I have already answered call with 180 (Ringing state) and then accept call with code 200 but at that time my app is getting hang

Getting such logs:

```
2019-09-05 17:23:24.914108+0530  Codec name is Video Toolbox codec
2019-09-05 17:23:24.914226+0530  MTU VALUE for codec #0 is 1336
2019-09-05 17:23:24.914265+0530  FrameSize for codec #0 is w:1280 h:720
2019-09-05 17:23:24.914297+0530  FPS for codec #0 is 15/1
2019-09-05 17:23:24.914327+0530  BandWidth VALUE for codec #0 is avg:256000 max:256000
video available: 117:23:24.914           pjsua_call.c !Answering call 0: code=200
17:23:24.914         inv0x116850aa8  ..SDP negotiation done: Success
17:23:24.914          pjsua_media.c  ...Call 0: updating media..
17:23:24.915          pjsua_media.c  .....Media stream call00:0 is destroyed
17:23:24.915            pjsua_aud.c  ....Audio channel update..
17:23:24.915        strm0x1169ef828  .....VAD temporarily disabled
17:23:24.917        strm0x1169ef828  .....Encoder stream started
17:23:24.917        strm0x1169ef828  .....Decoder stream started

17:23:24.920          pjsua_media.c  ....Audio updated, stream #0: PCMU (sendrecv)
17:23:24.921          pjsua_media.c  .....Media stream call00:1 is destroyed
17:23:24.921            pjsua_vid.c  ....Video channel update..
17:23:25.011      vstenc0x1169f3428  .....Encoder stream started
17:23:25.011      vstdec0x1169f3428  .....Decoder stream started
17:23:25.011            pjsua_vid.c  .....Setting up RX..
17:23:25.011            pjsua_vid.c  ......Creating video window: type=stream, cap_id=-1, rend_id=0
17:23:25.011             vid_port.c  .......Opening device OpenGL renderer [OpenGL] for render: format=I420, size=1280x720 @22:1 fps
17:23:25.237       ios_opengl_dev.c  .......iOS OpenGL ES renderer successfully created
17:23:25.237             vid_port.c  .......Device OpenGL renderer [OpenGL] opened: format=BGRA, size=1280x720 @22:1 fps
17:23:25.242             vid_conf.c  .......Added port 0 (OpenGL renderer)
17:23:25.242            pjsua_vid.c  .......stream window id 0 created for cap_dev=-1 rend_dev=0
17:23:25.242            pjsua_vid.c  .......Window 0 created
17:23:25.246             vid_conf.c  ......Added port 1 (vstdec0x1169f3428)
17:23:25.246             vid_conf.c  ......Port 1 (vstdec0x1169f3428) transmitting to port 0 (OpenGL renderer)
17:23:25.246       ios_opengl_dev.c  ......Starting ios opengl stream
17:23:25.249            pjsua_vid.c  .....Setting up TX..
17:23:25.250             vid_conf.c  ......Added port 2 (vstenc0x1169f3428)
17:23:25.250            pjsua_vid.c  ......Creating video window: type=preview, cap_id=2, rend_id=0
17:23:25.250             vid_port.c  .......Opening device Front Camera [AVF] for capture: format=I420, size=1280x720 @15:1 fps
17:23:25.332             vid_port.c  .......Device Front Camera [AVF] opened: format=I420, size=1280x720 @15:1 fps
```

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem with iOS platform. If you using pjsua_call_answer2, you could replace 180 (PJSIP_SC_RINGING) to 183 (PJSIP_SC_PROGRESS). It work fine with "out_auto_transmit = true"